# Typescript: button type prop typescript compilation error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this button component:

```
<button
        className={internalClassName}
        onClick={onClick ?? undefined}
        disabled={disabled}
        title={title}
        style={style}
        type={type}
        {...event}
    >
        {icon && <Icon icon={icon} size={iconSize} color={iconColor} />}
        { text }
        { children }
</button>
```

where type is

```
type ButtonTypes = 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset' | undefined;
```

Problem is that typescript compiler complains about the prop type with:

> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"submit" | "reset" | "button" | undefined'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"submit" | "reset" | "button" | undefined'.

Why it says is a string | undefined when I declared it as 'submit' | 'reset' | 'button' | undefined?

Comment: You probably meant to use an enum? I don't think `'button'` is a type. - I'm likely wrong here, since https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrsYB7AdgFXBAzlAvFAcgCMFkUCoAfQrOIgWwEtgLqCAnbCFqqOFACYQAZoxQQBAbgBQ0gMaoswWKVQZIALhWI1mHPmKrykoA works just fine.

Comment: Are you sure that line is what's causing the issue? This does not reproduce for me - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-forked-52e3c?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: the error is in the <button /> element

Comment: This error is saying you're passing a random string as the value and not one of `submit`, `reset`, or `button` – are you sure your value that you're passing as `type` is strictly typed as a `ButtonTypes` and not inferred as a `string`?

Comment: I think the problem is the other props. I have a "type" prop that could be any Button prop (button, reset, submit and undefined) and also some custom prop, like success, warning, etc. 


The component uses that type success, for example, for get the right className. So I need something that it accepts as a right tipe, and exludes the others

Answer (score 1):

Ok, update:

It seems that the spreading prop event is the cause of the problems

```
{...event}
```

Comment: Useful answer, run into the issue only when spreading props. Did anyone find a solution to this yet?